# select query using single or two input parameter in sql proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Suppose I have 2 textboxes namely id and name. If I pass id it should show data from that table or name is passed it should show data. I want to do it only in a single stored procedure.

```
Alter proc allview(
@employeefName varchar(30),
@employeelName varchar(30)
)

as
begin
if(@employeelName=null)
begin
select * from employeeTable
where employeefName=@employeefName
end

if(@employeefName=null)
begin
Select * from employeeTable
where employeelName=@employeelName
end

end
```

Comment: Please, reform your question in order to be more clear and also containing the things you have tried

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: I'd suggest not using a stored proc for a query like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use that

```
 select * from employeeTable
 where employeelName=@employeelName OR employeefName=@employeefName
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement, What I understood is the following

You have proc with 2 Parameters
If The value is passed to both the Parameters you want the results to be based on both otherwise based on only the one which has been passed.

In this case, you may try the below logic

```
Alter PROCEDURE allview
(
    @employeefName varchar(30),
    @employeelName varchar(30)
)
as
begin

    select 
        * 
        from employeeTable
            where 
            (
                (
                    ISNULL(@employeefName,'')=''
                    OR
                    employeefName=@employeefName
                )
                OR
                (
                    ISNULL(@employeelName,'')=''
                    OR
                    employeelName=@employeelName
                )
            )

end
```